# Understanding a missing rule for summations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I am reading a well known book about statistics. In one of their proofs they have the following two lines

$ - \sum_{x=0}^X \sum_{y=0}^Y p(x,y)\log[p(x)p(y\mid x)]$

$ - \sum_{x=0}^X \sum_{y=0}^Y p(x,y)\log [p(x)] - \sum_{x=0}^X \sum_{y=0}^Y p(x,y)\log [p(y\mid x)]$

I am confused about how the second follows from the first. I think there is some rule for sums that I do not know. Can someone explain.

Comment: In the first line, is $\log(p)$ supposed to be $\log[p(x)p(y\mid x) ]$?

Comment: Yes, it is. @Jesse

Comment: I think your first expression should be-$$ - \sum_{x=0}^X \sum_{y=0}^Y p(x,y)log(p(x)p(y|x)) $$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$log\ (ab)=log \ a+log \ b$$

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align}H(X, Y) & = - \sum_x \sum_y p(x,y) \log[p(x,y)]
\\ & = - \sum_x \sum_y p(x,y) \log[p(x)p(y\mid x)] & \ast
\\ & = - \sum_x \sum_y p(x,y) (\log[p(x)])+\log[p(y\mid x)]) & \star
\\ & = - \sum_x \sum_y p(x,y)\log[p(x)] - \sum_x\sum_y p(x,y) \log[p(y\mid x)]
\end{align}$

$\ast$ Your original post, on the first line, contained an error here.

$\star$ because the logarithm of a product is the sum of logarithms. $\log ab = \log a + log b$

That is all